# The Difference between /*<![CDATA[*/ and //<![CDATA[

Tags: javascript, blogger, cdata, blogspot

I'm a Blogger blog user. I once see a template locating script inside CDATA tag like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/*<![CDATA[*/
------script------
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

While, I before see a similiar code like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
------script------
//]]>
</script>
```

The only different is that `/*<![CDATA[*/` and `//<![CDATA[`. I wonder whether those both have different effect, or advantages. I also wonder the purpose of differing those. Here is always waiting insight from you, and your answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.

`//` comments out the line

`/*` comments out code until it finds a `*/` … which is at the end of the line in your example.

Comment: Would you extend your answer, please?

Comment: @AtoxEl-madani - Extend it how? There doesn't seem to be anything else left to say.

Comment: I have not just got it.

Comment: What's not to get about "There is no difference"?

Answer (score 1):

`//` comments out the text until the end of the line

`/*` comments out everything, irrespective of line endings, until it encounters `*/`

Since the `*/` is at the end of the line in your example, there is effectively no difference. However, there is a reason why you sometimes see `/*` `*/` comments instead of `//` comments for a CDATA section. Specifically, if the HTTP response body was being assembled programmatically, and you didn't have control over it, and the process removed line break characters it deemed unnecessary (in order to minimize the size of the output), and your script immediately followed the CDATA comment (because the process overzealously removed a line break it shouldn't have), it might look like this:

`//<![CDATA[var MyVariable = 'This statement does something.';`

In this case, `MyVariable` would not be declared or assigned because the statement is really just part of the comment. But if `/*` `*/` were used, as in this example:

`/*<![CDATA[*/var MyVariable = 'This statement does something.';`

...the comment ends before the code begins and the code would be executed as intended.

It's a fine point, but that's the reason you see it done.